# 18.04 does not shutdown, it goes into suspend modus

Tags: suspend, shutdown, 18.04

I cannot shut down my laptop, it goes into suspend modus. After having shut down I even see the logo of Lenovo on the display as if it would reboot and go into suspend modus. The shutdown button LED is blinking. If I close it and open it again it will turn on.

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

in /etc/default/grub

was changed to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

my laptop is a thinkpad E480, I don't know whether the information about graphic card is important

here:

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
```

Comment: now it restarts, afters some tries to fix that and updating the grub and so on, it restarts :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it :) finally

steps:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

that caused a automatic update popup from ubuntu after having pressed ok button it was something installed, I am posting the log file from this time (of course most of these updates are not related to this issue, but anyway)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     224 Mai 17 21:33 rfkill.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1915 Mai 17 21:33 python3-launchpadlib.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2058 Mai 17 21:33 python3-lazr.restfulclient.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     653 Mai 17 21:33 python3-oauth.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4115 Mai 17 21:33 python3-zope.interface.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1218 Mai 17 21:33 python3-wadllib.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2973 Mai 17 21:33 python3-simplejson.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1199 Mai 17 21:33 python3-lazr.uri.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     234 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     423 Mai 17 21:33 libpoppler73:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     293 Mai 17 21:33 libpoppler-glib8:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     920 Mai 17 21:33 poppler-utils.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     292 Mai 17 21:33 libpoppler-qt5-1:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     473 Mai 17 21:33 libcurl3-gnutls:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2365 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2-common.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     613 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2-cli.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     679 Mai 17 21:33 libapache2-mod-php7.2.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     478 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2-curl.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     292 Mai 17 21:33 libcurl4:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     454 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2-gd.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     478 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2-json.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     646 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2-mysql.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     514 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2-opcache.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     526 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2-readline.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     882 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2-xml.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     466 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2-bz2.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     526 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2-mbstring.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     466 Mai 17 21:33 php7.2-zip.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1198 Mai 17 21:33 gnome-terminal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   30284 Mai 17 21:33 gnome-terminal-data.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     486 Mai 17 21:33 nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2278 Mai 17 21:33 gnome-software-common.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4266 Mai 17 21:33 gnome-software.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     241 Mai 17 21:33 command-not-found-data.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     749 Mai 17 21:33 python3-commandnotfound.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     400 Mai 17 21:33 command-not-found.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     810 Mai 17 21:33 uuid-runtime.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1004 Mai 17 21:33 mount.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 Mai 17 21:33 linux-image-4.13.0-41-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     384 Mai 17 21:33 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-41-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 Mai 17 21:33 linux-signed-image-4.13.0-41-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 Mai 17 21:33 linux-image-4.13.0-39-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     384 Mai 17 21:33 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-39-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 Mai 17 21:33 linux-signed-image-4.13.0-39-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10305 Mai 17 21:33 util-linux.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     301 Mai 17 21:33 fdisk.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     262 Mai 17 21:33 libsmartcols1:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     242 Mai 17 21:33 libmount1:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     242 Mai 17 21:33 libfdisk1:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     242 Mai 17 21:33 libblkid1:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     237 Mai 17 21:33 libuuid1:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     814 Mai 17 21:33 bsdutils.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     436 Mai 17 21:28 sdparm.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     411 Mai 17 21:28 qt-at-spi:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3746 Mai 17 21:28 python-qt4.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     396 Mai 17 21:28 python-sip.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1724 Mai 17 21:28 net-tools.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     372 Mai 17 21:28 libqtassistantclient4:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     444 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-test:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     732 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-svg:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     428 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-sql-mysql:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     500 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-scripttools:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1123 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-help:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     647 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-designer:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     872 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-declarative:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1216 Mai 17 21:28 libqtgui4:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     500 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-xmlpatterns:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     436 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-sql:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     723 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-script:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     774 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-network:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     191 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-dbus:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     372 Mai 17 21:28 qdbus.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1565 Mai 17 21:28 qtchooser.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     439 Mai 17 21:28 libqtdbus4:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     436 Mai 17 21:28 libqt4-xml:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1028 Mai 17 21:28 libqtcore4:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1095 Mai 17 21:28 qtcore4-l10n.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5194 Mai 17 21:28 laptop-mode-tools.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     278 Mai 17 21:28 libmng2:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      63 Mai 17 21:28 tlp.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     104 Mai 17 21:28 tlp-rdw.list
```