# Ubuntu screen freeze on shutdown

Tags: shutdown, 18.04

Am using the latest Ubuntu 18.04 LTS(**Not** using dual boot). I am having 4 partitions on my laptop. Now there are two cases.

1. Shutdown when no partition (disk) is mounted
2. Shutdown when any of partition is mounted

In first case everything goes right.

But in second case screen freezes when I click on shutdown.

So everytime I have to unmount all partitions and then I have to shutdown. Is there any way I can avoid unmounting partitions all time.

I have tried editing grub acpi=force. Secure boot is off. But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this post might serve you well; I had the same problem as you and following its instructions fixed it for me.

[18.04 does not shutdown, it goes into suspend modus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037460/18-04-does-not-shutdown-it-goes-into-suspend-modus)

I **was** using a dual boot (Windows 10/Ubuntu) Intel machine however ([Full specs can be found here](https://pastebin.com/iWUCKTUN)); as far as I can tell this is a graphics issue though.

Finally, mine hung the first time I shutdown (forcing a final forced shutdown) but after I booted it up after that it runs perfectly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks this helped. But installing laptop-mode-tools removed TLP from my computer as they cannot work together. But that should be fine. I don't think that it is graphics issue. Doesn't matter. Thanks a lot.