# Problem powering off my computer on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: power-management, shutdown

After powering off, sometimes my computer doesn't power off and the desktop freezes. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [18.04 does not shutdown, it goes into suspend modus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037460/18-04-does-not-shutdown-it-goes-into-suspend-modus)

Comment: try using `sudo init 0` sir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the grub file.

Enter the Terminal using ALT+CTRL+T or from the serach, and enter the following command

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

The text editor will open. Search for the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and edit it to the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet noresume acpi=force reboot=pci"
```

After that go back to the terminal, and write:

```
sudo update-grub
```

That should fix it